# Cakephp radio button with out label

Tags: html, forms, cakephp

I need create following html code for working with bootstap

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio">
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

So I need single radio button with out any label and legend. I just try as follows.

```
echo $this->Form->radio('Answer.0.correct', array(
    'value' => 1,   
));
```

It has generate following html

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="Answer0Correct_" name="data[Answer][0][correct]">
<input type="radio" value="value" id="Answer0CorrectValue" name="data[Answer][0][correct]">
<label for="Answer0CorrectValue">1</label>
```

I set label option as false.

```
echo $this->Form->radio('Answer.0.correct', array(
    'value' => 1,   
    'label' => false,
));
```

But it had create unwanted radio with fieldset.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Correct</legend>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="Answer0Correct_" name="data[Answer][0][correct]">
    <input type="radio" value="value" id="Answer0CorrectValue" name="data[Answer][0][correct]">
    <label for="Answer0CorrectValue">1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="label" id="Answer0CorrectLabel" name="data[Answer][0][correct]">
    <label for="Answer0CorrectLabel"></label>
</fieldset>
```

How can i create single radio button (with his hidden field)?

Answer (score 2):

[more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aradio)

```
$options = array('1' => false, '2' => false);
$attributes = array('legend' => false, 'label' => false);
echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$attributes = array('1' =>false);
echo $this->Form->radio('Answer.0.correct', $attributes);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot generate the desired output with the Form Helper, you can still just write the HTML code in your view file. So in your index.ctp or *.ctp just put

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="radio">
   </span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

and you are all set. I don't understand why you HAVE to generate this markup with the Form Helper.

Comment: I know it. But i need do it best way.